# Showing Inactive Campaigns in Lookup field for Inline Edit

Tags: lookup, campaign

We have the need for users to be able to edit a campaign from the list view and add a parent campaign. The issue is these parent campaigns need to stay inactive but the user is unable to pull up an inactive campaign from the list view:
[image: Inline Edit]

I was wondering if there was a way to relax the restriction or add a condition to this lookup, similar to the standard parent campaign lookup on the campaign object:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. The system basically only allows users to work with active campaigns. You would need to make the parent campaign active first.